# Is there a way to draw to the screen faster with StdDraw in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, stddraw

I am using the StdDraw library from `https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java`. To my knowledge it just implements a simple interface for drawing to the screen using JFrame.

In my implementation, I simply have a 2d array of pixels, and I am drawing each one like so:

```java
StdDraw.clear()
for (int y = 0; y < Engine.HEIGHT; y += 1) {
    for (int x = 0; x < Engine.WIDTH; x += 1) {
        map[x][y].draw((float) x / Engine.WIDTH, (float) y / Engine.HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

This, however, is extremely slow. Like insanely slow. Not to mention that I have to redraw the entire screen every time I want to update it.

I clear the screen and then redraw every pixel. There is no way this is how it supposed to work, but I just don't really know where to look. Some suggestions on what I should look out for would be really helpful!

Comment: If you're willing to use plain Java Swing, the Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how to draw on the drawing JPanel with Graphics and Graphics2D methods.

Comment: Draw yourself for a better understanding of event driven drawing. It is not difficult to override a JPanel's paintComponent and draw yourself. Pixel drawing _is_ slow. You may draw an image instead, and fill the BufferedImage using its createGraphics.

Comment: Joop's advice to look into using BufferedImage is good.  But you haven't explained what `map` is.  It's a two-dimensional array, but of what?  Which class's `draw` is being called?  It could be that the draw is fast (unlikely) and getting to it through map is slow (unlikely).  However unlikely, we want to eliminate ambiguities in case a cause is hiding among them.

Comment: It looks like you are using Princeton's StdDraw library.  But there is no ".draw" in it. https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html  Are you mixing classes?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the final answer, but a way to put some measurable code on the table. `BufferedImage` is the way to go, but for reference on my not-too-fast system, this code takes 5 seconds to draw 40 million pixels, or 125 milliseconds per megapixel.  How may pixels do you have?!?  This code uses a call to `line` as a proxy for drawing a single pixel because the class doesn't offer single pixel drawing, but theoretically code that draws an actual pixel like you do should be faster.

What class is YOUR `map`?

How many pixels?

What amount of time is "insanely slow"?

```
public class SandBox {


    public static void main (String [] args) {

        boolean [] [] map = new boolean [1000] [1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                map [i] [j] = true;
            }
        }
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame ();
        myFrame.setSize (1100, 1100);
        SPanel myPanel = new SPanel ();
        myPanel.myMap = map;
        myFrame.add (myPanel);
        myFrame.setVisible (true);
    }

} // class SandBox


class SPanel extends JPanel {

    public boolean [] [] myMap;


    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        g.drawString ("Hello", 30, 30);
        Instant start = Instant.now ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            g.setColor (new Color (0, 0, 0));
            drawMap (g);
            g.setColor (new Color (255, 0, 0));
            drawMap (g);
            g.setColor (new Color (0, 255, 0));
            drawMap (g);
            g.setColor (new Color (0, 0, 255));
            drawMap (g);
        }
        reportElapsed (start);
        g.drawRect (50, 50, 1000, 1000);
    }


    void drawMap (Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                if (myMap [i] [j] == true) {
                    g.drawLine (i + 50, j + 50, i + 50, j + 50);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static void reportElapsed (Instant start) {
        Duration elapsed = Duration.between (start, Instant.now ());
        long millis = elapsed.toMillis ();
        System.out.println ("Duration (ms):  " + millis + ".");
    } // reportElapsed


} // class SPanel
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple and it is fast!

But you have to use correct library, i.e Picture.java class available at

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Picture.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    int SIZE = 250;
    
    Random rnd = new Random();
    
    int[][] mapR = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    int[][] mapG = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    int[][] mapB = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        
    {
        mapR[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(256);
        mapG[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(256);
        mapB[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(256);      }
        
    
    Picture p = new Picture(SIZE, SIZE);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            
            p.set(i, j, new Color(mapR[i][j], mapG[i][j], mapB[i][j]));
    
    p.show();

}
```